# Remove Bullets from menu in wordpress

Tags: css

I have tried a few codes to try and remove the bullets from the list style menus on my site, but they are still present.

[image].

How can I get rid of these bullets?

Comment: Add this to your style `ul{list-style: none}`

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for

```
ul{
   list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Great, it worked! Thank you!!

Comment: @user6785728 Glad it help, consider accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`ul, li{list-style:none;}` should work fine